# CASE Statement inside HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query:

```
select distinct RL.LINK_ID as LINK_ID, RLG.[ZLEVEL] 
from RDF_LINK as RL, RDF_LINK_GEOMETRY as RLG 
where (RL.BRIDGE = 'Y' OR RL.TUNNEL = 'Y') AND RL.LINK_ID = RLG.[LINK_ID]
```

which gets me this output:

```
RecNo   LINK_ID     ZLEVEL
1       26018528    0
2       53678211    1
3       53678211    0
4       53681432    1
5       53681432    0
6       53682353    0
7       53682353    1
8       53683791    1
9       53683791    0
10      53691049    1
11      53691049    0
```

Now I want single LINK_ID if there are two (and for them ZLevel is 1)

For same I tried `GROUP BY` and `Having with CASE statement` but didn't able to get the output as I want.

Comment: Provide expected output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAVING would be used when, after grouping, you would want to filter out some groups.

However, you actually want to create one group for each `LINK_ID`, and to get the maximum `ZLEVEL` value for each group:

```
SELECT RL.Link_ID,
       max(RLG.ZLevel)
FROM RDF_Link AS RL
JOIN RDF_Link_Geometry AS RLG USING (Link_ID)
WHERE RL.Bridge = 'Y'
   OR RL.Tunnel = 'Y'
GROUP BY RL.Link_ID
```

Comment: Absolutely True... Thanks